# What graphic chips could be used with a W65C816

Tags: microprocessor

I'd like to build an 80's type computer using the W65C816 CPU. If possible, I'd like to use a dedicated graphics chip, and would prefer to avoid going the FPGA route. Could anyone suggest what I should start looking for, or recommend any currently produced chips that might work? Sincere thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Designing and building a graphic card is complicated. Try to find an ISA based graphic card. It will be easy to interface with ISA hardware.

You can also use a Nokia LCD display with a SPI or 8080 bus. 8080 interface is quite simple to deal in the case of your CPU.

Comment: Has anyone had any experience w/ the Picaso-SGC? http://www.4dsystems.com.au/prod.php?id=87 Would such a controller have any potential in terms of interfacing w/ a Z80 or W65C816? Many thanks in advance.